# How do I manage a dynamic amount of sub pages in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently building a website with vue.js, I'm using an API to get data to feed into my website. Up to this point I could manage just fine with the surface level knowledge I have but right now I run into some issues when trying to setup a route with multiple sub pages. Here's what I've come up with so far:

Here's my template:

```js
<RouterLink :to="getSpeakingUrl(facility.name, facility.id, 'facility-detail', parents)">
  {{ facility.name }}
</RouterLink>
```

getSpeakingUrl-function:

```js
getSpeakingUrl(value, elem_id, route, parents) {
  const slug = generateSlug(value);
  return { name: route, params: { slug: slug, id: elem_id, parents: parents } };
}
```

Route:

```js
{
  path: "/facility/:parents?/:slug-:id",
  name: "facility-detail",
  component: FacilityDetail,
  meta: {
    title: 'facility detail',
    breadcrumb: [
      { name: 'all facilities', link: 'facilities' },
      { name: 'facility-detail' }
    ]
  }
},
```

I then tried to just save all the different sub pages into a string and just paste it before the actual route:

```js
data() {
  return {
    item: [],
    id: this.$route.params.id.split('-').slice(-1)[0],
    parents: this.$route.path.split('/facility/').slice(-1)[0]
  };
},
```

this theoretically works, ideally my route should look like this:

http://localhost:5173/facility/facility-1/facility-2/facility-3/facility-4

but as soon as I convert the url into a string it parses the "/" to "%2F". I also feel like this is a really sloppy solution and not the way its intended but I never had to do something like this so I'm a little lost right now. Is there a better way to setup my routes for multiple sub pages?